# WCF https with only server certificate

Tags: c#, wcf, https

I trying to do WCF using self-signed certificate. I found some solutions,but they need client to know clinet certificate before connection.
I would like make client works as browser(When browser use web server certificate).
I mean browser don't know webserver's certificate before connection, it can obtain it from web server. 
My server's web.config:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="false" />
    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="security" name="WebApplicationExchange.UKService">
        <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="security" contract="WebApplicationExchange.IUKService">
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost" />
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpsBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="https://localhost/UKService/UKService.svc" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="security">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="false" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceCredentials>
            <userNameAuthentication userNamePasswordValidationMode="Custom" customUserNamePasswordValidatorType="ServiceAuthorization.PasswordValidator,ServiceAuthorization" />
            <windowsAuthentication allowAnonymousLogons="false" />
          </serviceCredentials>
          <serviceAuthorization principalPermissionMode="Custom">
            <authorizationPolicies>
              <add policyType="ServiceAuthorization.AuthorizationPolicy,ServiceAuthorization" />
            </authorizationPolicies>
          </serviceAuthorization>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="security">
          <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">
            <transport clientCredentialType="Basic" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

It works fine with web browsers.

But client show error:
Could not establish trust connection for secure channel SSL / TLS with authority "localhost: 56389".
Client code:

```
System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress eaSecurity = new System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress("https://localhost:56389/UKService.svc");
                var binding = new System.ServiceModel.BasicHttpBinding();
                binding.Security.Mode = System.ServiceModel.BasicHttpSecurityMode.TransportWithMessageCredential;
                binding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = System.ServiceModel.HttpClientCredentialType.None;
                binding.Security.Message.ClientCredentialType = System.ServiceModel.BasicHttpMessageCredentialType.UserName;


                var securityFactory = new System.ServiceModel.ChannelFactory<ServiceReference1.IUKService>(binding, eaSecurity);
                securityFactory.Credentials.UserName.UserName = "test";
                securityFactory.Credentials.UserName.Password = "test";
                myService = securityFactory.CreateChannel();
```

Any ideas how to solve this?

**UPDATE:**
I look deeper in error stack and find following:
System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: The remote certificate is invalid according to the results of authentication.
I tryed this code:

```
  ClientCredentials cc = securityFactory.Endpoint.Behaviors.Find<ClientCredentials>();

                cc.UserName.UserName = "test";
                cc.UserName.Password = "test";

               cc.ServiceCertificate.Authentication.CertificateValidationMode = X509CertificateValidationMode.None;
```

But it doesn't help.

Comment: Browsers do it by having a human manually verify the certificate. Is that what you're trying to do?

Comment: not exactly, i mean browser don't know webserver's certificate before connection, it can obtain it from web server.

Comment: Right, but that's only useful if the person using the browser already has enough information to verify the certificate. Are you planning to use human intervention? Or do you already have enough information to verify the certificate?

Comment: I prefer do not verify certificate. I wrote code in update. But error is the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solve it this way:

```
System.Net.ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += new System.Net.Security.RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(RemoteCertValidateCallback);
 public static bool RemoteCertValidateCallback(object sender, X509Certificate cert, X509Chain chain, System.Net.Security.SslPolicyErrors error)
        {
            return true;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your certificate is not trusted by the client. This has nothing to do with client certificates or downloading the certificate from the browser.

In order for the server certificate to be accepted by te client, you need to either:

- Buy a certificate from a trusted certificate authority
- Add the certificate (or its root) to the client machine's certificate store or
- Disable certificate validation.

Comment: Disable certificate validation - it is suited for me. I wrote folowing code:ClientCredentials cc = securityFactory.Endpoint.Behaviors.Find<ClientCredentials>();

                cc.UserName.UserName = "test";
                cc.UserName.Password = "test";

                cc.ServiceCertificate.Authentication.CertificateValidationMode = X509CertificateValidationMode.None;

Comment: But this doesn't help. Error is the same